# How to find common rows between two data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames in R:

My goal is two find the common rows between two data frames according to two columns and select them in the first one.
For example, I have the below data frames:

```
c<- data.frame(A = c(4,6,7), B = c(5,9,8),C = c("T","T","F"))
d<- data.frame(A = c(6,7,3),B = c(9,8,3))
```

And I want the result to be:

```
# A B C
# 6 9 T
# 7 8 F
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was my first question and I was not familiar with how to use it. I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
c<- data.frame(A = c(4,6,7), B = c(5,9,8),C = c("T","T","F"))
d<- data.frame(A = c(6,7,3),B = c(9,8,3),C = c("T","F","F"))

merge(c, d, by= c("A", "B", "C"))
```

Output:

```
  A B C
1 6 9 T
2 7 8 F
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

# set as data table
lapply(list(c,d), \(i)setDT(i))

# join
c[d, on=names(c), nomatch=0][1]
```

I have a feeling I may not have understood fully when you said "select them in the first one". If so, please explain

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner join on all columns:

```r
dplyr::inner_join(c, d, by = c('A', 'B', 'C'))
#>   A B C
#> 1 6 9 T
#> 2 7 8 F
```

Comment: It is a data frame @Quinten. The OP says that we wans to select rows from the first data frame, which to me means subsetting the data frame. In fact, as I am writing this, the OP has edited to show that column names are expected in the output.